# How to use core data for offline(source core data)-online(server data) mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, offlineapps

I am working on iOS app which works in both offline and online.
The app is designed in such a way that the functionality of the app will defer according to subscription type like Basic and Premium.
Basic users will be able to use the app in online mode only, whereas premium users will have the ability to use the app in both online and offline mode.

When the app is used in online mode, web service will be called and response data will be parsed and will be stored in a object of NSObject class ( Business Object ). This NSObject is used to bind the data to the respective view controllers. This functionality is same for both Basic and Premium users who are using the app in online mode. But in addition to this functionality for Premium users we will store the data which we got from server into the core data to make the app work in offline mode. Before storing the data into the core data we are using a conversion class(Subclass of NSObject ) which is used to convert the object of NSObject class to the respective object of NSManagedObject class (NSObject-->conversion class-->NSManagedObject ). 
Now here we are facing the performance issue in offline mode while performing the conversions from object of NSManagedObject class to the respective object of NSObject class(NSManagedObject-->conversion class-->NSObject).
Is it possible to get rid of NSObject and use only NSManagedObject throughout the app.

---

**Please note**, we dont want to store any data of the Basic user in core data while the app is in online mode.

Comment: Yes, the entities will be saved to persistent store (SQLite) only when you call `save:` on their respective `context`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing CoreData you should always use NSManagedObjects as your models, creating two different classes to the same object makes no sense, it's slow and you will have many errors.

If Basic users can only work in online mode, you should save all data in your database, but implement rules on the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Core Data but not persistent store, use In-Memory store. For the exact same model but store persistent use SQLite store. The only thing that changes is how you create the store.